# iterate through an object with jquery and parse variables in table

Tags: jquery, json, loops, object, iteration

Im try to iterate with jquery through multidimensional Object i got from a JSON Url. I know how to do it in PHP but in Jquery its quiet new to me. Can you tell me how i do it the right way ?

This here is my Object Structure (I know its array but its because i printed it as array in PHP...the object structure is the same since the data source is the same JSON Url.

OBJECT Structure:

```
Array
(
    [rigs] => Array
        (
            [45334a] => Array
                (
                    [condition] => mining
                    [version] => 1.2.7
                    [driver] => amdgpu
                    [miner] => claymore-xmr
                    [gpus] => 6
                    [miner_instance] => 6
                    [miner_hashes] => 807.10 805.15 806.65 807.95 806.55 807.90
                    [bioses] => 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101
                    [meminfo] => GPU0:01.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU1:02.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU2:03.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU3:04.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU4:05.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU5:06.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
                    [vramsize] => 8 8 8 8 8 8
                    [drive_name] => KINGSTON SA400S37120G 50026B76760083DD
                    [mobo] => H81 Pro BTC R2.0
                    [lan_chip] => Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
                    [connected_displays] => 
                    [ram] => 7
                    [rack_loc] => devilrig
                    [ip] => 192.168.179.22
                    [server_time] => 1512871719
                    [uptime] => 1127
                    [miner_secs] => 1065
                    [rx_kbps] => 0.00
                    [tx_kbps] => 0.00
                    [load] => 0.45
                    [cpu_temp] => 33
                    [freespace] => 3.1
                    [hash] => 4841.3
                    [pool] => etn-eu1.nanopool.org:13333
                    [temp] => 74.00 73.00 74.00 74.00 74.00 52.00
                    [powertune] => 7 7 7 7 7 7
                    [voltage] => 1.150 1.150 1.150 1.150 1.150 1.150
                    [watts] => 
                    [fanrpm] => 1659 1924 1800 1659 1518 1518
                    [core] => 1380 1380 1380 1380 1380 1380
                    [mem] => 2150 2150 2150 2150 2150 2150
                )

            [469119] => Array
                (
                    [condition] => mining
                    [version] => 1.2.7
                    [driver] => amdgpu
                    [miner] => claymore
                    [gpus] => 3
                    [miner_instance] => 3
                    [miner_hashes] => 22.18 27.54 27.55
                    [bioses] => 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101 113-C9403100_101
                    [meminfo] => GPU0:01.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU1:03.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU2:04.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
                    [vramsize] => 8 8 8
                    [drive_name] => Hitachi HTS545050B9A302 111002PBL400P7GKD6DV
                    [mobo] => H81 Pro BTC R2.0
                    [lan_chip] => Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
                    [connected_displays] => 
                    [ram] => 4
                    [rack_loc] => dragonri
                    [ip] => 192.168.179.27
                    [server_time] => 1512871598
                    [uptime] => 79751
                    [miner_secs] => 79687
                    [rx_kbps] => 0.09
                    [tx_kbps] => 0.08
                    [load] => 0.20
                    [cpu_temp] => 20
                    [freespace] => 3.1
                    [hash] => 77.27
                    [pool] => pirl.minerpool.net:8002
                    [temp] => 69.00 55.00 69.00
                    [powertune] => 3 3 3
                    [voltage] => 0.862 0.887 0.868
                    [watts] => 
                    [fanrpm] => 1518 1518 1659
                    [core] => 1075 1075 1075
                    [mem] => 2000 2000 2000
                )

            [4699d6] => Array
                (
                    [condition] => mining
                    [version] => 1.2.7
                    [driver] => fglrx
                    [miner] => claymore-xmr
                    [gpus] => 5
                    [miner_instance] => 5
                    [miner_hashes] => 831.17 832.04 801.65 825.13 814.83
                    [bioses] => 113-2E3243U-X4H 115-C671GPI-200 113-2E3243U-X4J xxx-xxx-xxx 113-2E3240U-X4A
                    [meminfo] => GPU0:01.00.0:Radeon R9 390:113-2E3243U-X4H:SK Hynix H5GC4H24AJR:GDDR5:Hawaii
GPU1:02.00.0:Radeon R9 390:115-C671GPI-200:SK Hynix H5GC4H24AJR:GDDR5:Hawaii
GPU2:03.00.0:Radeon R9 390:113-2E3243U-X4J:Elpida EDW4032BABG:GDDR5:Hawaii
GPU3:04.00.0:Radeon R9 390:xxx-xxx-xxx:SK Hynix H5GC4H24AJR:GDDR5:Hawaii
GPU4:05.00.0:Radeon R9 390:113-2E3240U-X4A:SK Hynix H5GC4H24AJR:GDDR5:Hawaii
                    [vramsize] => 8 8 8 8 8
                    [drive_name] => WDC WD10EZEX-08WN4A0 WD-WCC6Y3FS9RVS
                    [mobo] => H81 Pro BTC R2.0
                    [lan_chip] => Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
                    [connected_displays] => 640x480
                    [ram] => 4
                    [rack_loc] => r9-rig
                    [ip] => 192.168.179.23
                    [server_time] => 1512871577
                    [uptime] => 83425
                    [miner_secs] => 83373
                    [rx_kbps] => 0.07
                    [tx_kbps] => 0.04
                    [load] => 0.54
                    [cpu_temp] => 40
                    [freespace] => 2.9
                    [hash] => 4104.82
                    [pool] => etn-eu1.nanopool.org:13333
                    [temp] => 72.00 60.00 61.00 73.00 54.00
                    [powertune] => 50 50 50 50 50
                    [voltage] => 0 0 0 0 0
                    [watts] => 
                    [fanrpm] => 2216 0 1924 2218 1557
                    [core] => 1040 1050 1040 1025 1010
                    [mem] => 1500 1500 1500 1500 1500
                )

            [46a259] => Array
                (
                    [condition] => stuck_miners
                    [version] => 1.2.7
                    [driver] => amdgpu
                    [miner] => claymore
                    [gpus] => 6
                    [miner_instance] => 5
                    [miner_hashes] => 24.31 28.13 24.35 00.00 24.38 24.95
                    [bioses] => 115-D000PIL-100 115-D000PIL-100 113-2E3470U.S5X 113-D00034-S07 115-D000PIL-100 113-C9403100_101
                    [meminfo] => GPU0:01.00.0:Radeon RX 480:115-D000PIL-100:Samsung K4G80325FB:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU1:02.00.0:Radeon RX 480:115-D000PIL-100:Samsung K4G80325FB:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU2:03.00.0:Radeon RX 480:113-2E3470U.S5X:Samsung K4G80325FB:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU3:04.00.0:Radeon RX 570:113-D00034-S07:SK Hynix H5GC4H24AJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU4:05.00.0:Radeon RX 480:115-D000PIL-100:Samsung K4G80325FB:GDDR5:Polaris10
GPU5:06.00.0:Radeon RX 580:113-C9403100_101:SK Hynix H5GQ8H24MJR:GDDR5:Polaris10
                    [vramsize] => 8 8 8 4 8 8
                    [drive_name] => KINGSTON SA400S37120G 50026B767600864A
                    [mobo] => H81 Pro BTC R2.0
                    [lan_chip] => Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
                    [connected_displays] => 
                    [ram] => 4
                    [rack_loc] => smallrig
                    [ip] => 192.168.179.26
                    [server_time] => 1512871730
                    [uptime] => 51631
                    [miner_secs] => 51569
                    [rx_kbps] => 0.09
                    [tx_kbps] => 0.09
                    [load] => 0.20
                    [cpu_temp] => 42
                    [freespace] => 3.2
                    [hash] => 126.12
                    [pool] => pirl.minerpool.net:8002
                    [temp] => 64.00 64.00 74.00 35.00 64.00 56.00
                    [powertune] => 5 5 5 5 5 5
                    [voltage] => 1.143 0.956 1.031 1.131 1.150 1.150
                    [watts] => 
                    [fanrpm] => 2294 1659 988 1659 1888 1518
                    [core] => 1232 1125 1191 1168 1232 1266
                    [mem] => 2000 2050 2000 300 2000 2000
                )

        )

    [total_hash] => 9149.51
    [alive_gpus] => 19
    [total_gpus] => 20
    [alive_rigs] => 4
    [total_rigs] => 4
    [current_version] => 1.2.7
    [avg_temp] => 64.5
    [capacity] => 95.0
    [per_info] => Array
        (
            [claymore-xmr] => Array
                (
                    [hash] => 8946
                    [per_alive_gpus] => 11
                    [per_total_gpus] => 11
                    [per_alive_rigs] => 2
                    [per_total_rigs] => 2
                    [per_hash-gpu] => 813.3
                    [per_hash-rig] => 4473.0
                    [current_time] => 1512871754
                )

            [claymore] => Array
                (
                    [hash] => 203
                    [per_alive_gpus] => 8
                    [per_total_gpus] => 9
                    [per_alive_rigs] => 2
                    [per_total_rigs] => 2
                    [per_hash-gpu] => 25.4
                    [per_hash-rig] => 101.5
                    [current_time] => 1512871754
                )

        )
```

How i tried to iterate through it to get the variables to embed it in html:

```
function GetRigTable() {

        var rigtdata = $.getJSON('http://ellaah.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes', function (rigdata) {

            $.each($.parseJSON(rigdata.rigs), function(key,rig){
                alert(rig.rack_loc);
            });

        });

    }
```

My mainproblem is that i need the keys of rigs and each one is different. 
could anyone maybe help me we a quickstart how to handle such a situation ? Would be quit nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since returned response is already an object type, you don't have to `$.parseJSON` it again. And to get the key of the iterating object, first parameter of `$.each` callback function is what you're looking for.

```
$.getJSON('http://ellaah.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes', function (rigdata) {
    $.each(rigdata.rigs, function(keyOfRig, rigValue) {
        console.log(keyOfRig, rigValue.rack_loc);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for...in` if you want to access the keys

```
    var rigtdata = $.getJSON('http://ellaah.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes', function (rigdata) {
        var rigs = $.parseJSON(rigdata.rigs);
        for(var key in rigs){
            alert(rigs[key].rack_loc);
            //Do whatever with key
        });

    });
```